# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getPart

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, cloud, storage

I have problem with upload image to google cloud storage in google app engine.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getPart(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/http/Part;

        at com.google.appengine.controller.PostNewsServlet.doPost (PostNewsServlet.java:89)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter (ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter (ServletHandler.java:1157)
```

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see javax.servlet.api version 3.0.1 and version 3.10 in your pom.xml but Google App Engine only support version 2.5

Comment: Thank your answer, 
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getPart need add version 3.0 or newer. hic

Comment: I see, then you will need a different solution for your upload. Have a look at Apache Fileupload https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/